# How to run light box only once?

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

I have created one light box which pops up every time we hit the home page of the site but I want show it once when user hits home page instead of showing it every time we hit home page. How can I do this?

Comment: In which language are you building the website? care to add tags for the same.

Comment: I am using pure html and javascript with no use of sessions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` or `cookies` for that. Test if the user has not visited your page yet (by getting the `visited`-key in this case) > open your lightbox and set the `visited` key then. Now each time the user opens your page the `visited`-key is not false and your lightbox will not be opened:

```
if( !window.localStorage.getItem("visited") ){
    alert(true);
    window.localStorage.setItem("visited", true);
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/UsfAh/

As the questioner asked (in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244089/how-to-run-light-box-only-once/15244999?noredirect=1#comment21497075_15244999)) that's maybe a better solution for him:

```
window.onunload = function(){
    window.localStorage.setItem("visited", true);
};
```

Comment: Hey @yckart its happening only once and it is not showing me even though I closed and again opened it in browser.I want that this should show me again when I close and again open the website in browser.

Comment: @Akki you can play a bit around with `onunload` which is triggerd if the user reloads your page...